# CS50 problem 2 - Readability // The grading is not working properly

Tags: c, cs50, readability

Hi there I am having an issue with CS50 problem set 2 specifically the readability task. The issue is when I input the preset values that are on the website to try out to test your program some of them don't work I am not sure why it doesn't work can anyone help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
  string text = get_string("Text: ");
  int letter_count = 0;
  int word_count = 0;
  int sentence_count = 0;

  for( int i=0;i < strlen(text);i++){

    if (isalpha(text[i])){
        letter_count ++;
    }
    else if(text[i] == ' '){
        word_count ++;
    }
    else if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
    {
        sentence_count ++;
    }
  }
  float L = ((float)letter_count / (float)word_count) * 100;
  float S = ((float)sentence_count / (float)word_count) * 100;
  float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

  if (index <= 16 && index >= 0)
  {
    printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(index));
  }
  else if (index >= 16)
  {
    printf("Grade 16+\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("Before Grade 1\n");
  }
  printf("%i Letter(s)\n", letter_count);
  printf("%i Word(s)\n", word_count+1);
  printf("%i Sentence(s)\n", sentence_count);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What are expected inputs/outputs?

Comment: the input is just a text which should we read character by character and through a formula it is check which grade of readability it belongs to but the problem is the output which should output a correct grade put for some of the texts it doesnt let me share and example

There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy. (Grade 9) <<<< this one should be a grade 9 according to the formula but in my output it shows a grade 10

Comment: Your method to count words is not accurate, because you count the gaps, not the words. (If you prepend a space before your example, you will get the correct grade.) Also, treating all spaces as gaps isn't good, either. Some people like to write two spaces after a sentence. Some people inadvertently end their lines with excess spaces. "␣So␣what?␣" and "So␣␣what␣?" should yield the same word and sentence count.

Comment: A better method is to count the beginning of words, when you have an alpha character preceded by a non-alpha character. (And pretend that there is a non-alpha character before the input. You'll probably need some similar logic to combine multi-character punctuation as in "WTF?!? I'm going crazy ...".)

Comment: `"Modify readability.c so that instead of outputting the number of letters, words, and sentences, it instead outputs the grade level as given by the Coleman-Liau index ..."` You forgot to remove the letter words and sentence counts.

Comment: ah I see thank you very much I will remove the letters, words, sentences, and thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check spaces for counting words, one space means `' '` indeed a word coming after. But if there is a space, it means there must be always a word in front. Like below;

> Hello World.

Here there are two words, but one space. To fix this, initializing `word` variable with `1` should do the work.

```
int word_count = 1;
```